# cleanest way to insert javascript code in html (inside javascript code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build some HTML using jquery and then inject that html into some div on my page. I want to build an anchor element. The href, and the label of my anchor element come from javascript variables. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    var href = 'http://testing123.com';
    var label = 'Anchor label';
    var anchor_element = '<a href="' + href + '">' + label + '</a>';
});
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea how I can properly construct my anchor element in javascript/jquery please.

Comment: what are you doing after that? I mean adding that HTML somewhere ??

Comment: What doesn't work about this? Looks fine to me.

Comment: What about this isn't working?  That seems correct to me.

Comment: `anchor_element` is just a string. If you want to insert it somewhere in your document, you need to use an appropiate function for that (by selecting an other element in your dom tree and appending it as a child for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append the result to the DOM. add this line at the end.

```
$('body').append(anchor_element);
```

You can ofcourse replace 'body' with any other selector as you like.

```
$(function(){
    var href = 'http://testing123.com';
    var label = 'Anchor label';
    var anchor_element = '<a href="' + href + '">' + label + '</a>';
    $('body').append(anchor_element); // add the element to <body>
});
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gCEL/)

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery syntax:

```
$('<a/>', {
    href: 'http://testing123.com',
    text: 'Anchor label'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: This type of syntax isn't used enough for my liking.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var href = 'http://testing123.com';
var label = 'Anchor label';

// Create a dynamic anchor element and set the href and label
var $anchor_element = $('<a/>', {
    href: href,
    text: label
});

// Append the newly created element to DOM,
// here we are appending it to the body
$('body').append($anchor_element);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnStM/)

Answer (score 0):

What ever you have write is working fine,But You forgot to append it to the target.

```
var href = 'http://testing123.com';
var label = 'Anchor label';

var anchor_element = '<a href="' + href + '">' + label + '</a>';
$('#target').append(anchor_element);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1357/)